# How to allow derived collections in generic method

Tags: c#, collections, casting, covariance

I have multiple classes representing objects which all have bounds described by a [Unity Rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.html) field.  (`Zone, Room, Structure, Tunnel, Room`...)

These objects are often placed in collections. (`List<Zone>, List<Room>`...)

I want to have single static utility method that will test if a single one of these overlaps any the bounds from a collection of such objects, without having to cast a List using LINQ.

```
public static bool BoundsOverlapsOtherBounds(Bounds bound, List<Bounds>)
```

How should I use C# polymorphism, interfaces, covariance to achieve this, without needing to cast `List<Room>` or `List<Zone>` to `List<Bounds>` first?

My attempts so far have always produced "*Cannot covert X to Y"* compiler errors.

Comment: Can u try `List<T>`

Comment: If `Zone`, `Room`, etc. implement some common interface that exposes the rectangular boundaries then you can perform the comparison without casting the collection. `bool BoundsOverlapsOtherBounds<T>(IHasBoundaries bound, IEnumerable<IHasBoundardies> others) where T : IHasBoundaries`.

Comment: Can you share the code for one of your `Zone`/`Room`/… classes? I assumed they all inherit from the `Bounds` class but as always with assumptions, that might not be the case.

Comment: @ScottHannen the `T` generic doesn't add anything there since it's not used in any of the parameters. Imo it should be used in case you want to use a `List` instead of an `IEnumerable` (`IEnumerable` will automatically work for a shared parent/interface without the need for generics). So for `List` it would be something like: `BoundsOverlapsOtherBounds<T>(Bounds bound, List<T> others) where T : Bounds`. which I assume would be along the lines of the solution proposed by sri harsha

Comment: @Knoop - The generic argument would be inferred. As for `IEnumerable<T>` vs `List`, that's just a habit. I should have just used `List` to avoid introducing something else on top. The question didn't specify that everything inherited from `Bounds`. But it's the same either way. If it does, the generic solution works. Or if you just implement some interface that exposes the boundaries, it would work exactly the same way.

Comment: @ScottHannen It was more that you didn't use the `T` in any of the parameters, which made it useless. The code from your comment, when using `List` instead of `IEnumerable`, would still not compile if you fed it a `List<Room>`. Anyway the answer you added was the way I was trying to say it should be done if you wanted to use generics. You are right that in that case there's no need to specify the `T` in the call and it will be inferred, but that was not my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because (as implied) all of these types already inherit from `Bounds`, you don't need to cast `List<Room>` or `List<Zone>` to `List<Bounds>`.

You can do this:

```
bool BoundsOverlapsOtherBounds<T>(Bounds bound, List<T> bounds) where T : Bounds
```

The generic constraint means that you can pass any `List<T>` to the method as long as `T` implements or inherits `Bounds`.

So if you have a `List<Room>` you can pass it to the method without explicitly casting it:

```
var rooms = new List<Room>();
var otherBounds = new Bounds();
var overlaps = BoundsOverlapsOtherBounds(otherBounds, rooms);
```

You don't even have to specify the generic argument because it's inferred.

---

If by any chance these objects don't share a common type, then it's likely a case where they should. Inheritance is *a* solution, but we don't need to use it to cause types to have a common characteristic. Sometimes that paints us into a corner. An interface might also make sense:

```
interface IHasBoundaries // not a great name?
{
    Boundaries Bounds { get; }
}
```

That's polymorphism. *Multiple forms* (or types) can implement the interface, and you don't care at all about what makes them different - only what they have in common. You can write code that deals with `IHasBoundaries` and in that context that's the only thing you need to know about those objects, that they implement the interface.

Then your method looks like this:

```
bool BoundsOverlapsOtherBounds<T>(IHasBoundaries bound, List<T> bounds) 
    where T : IHasBoundaries
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a `List<Zone>` is different then a `List<Bounds>`. You can add a `Room` to a `List<Bounds>` but not to a `List<Zone>` which is why they cannot be converted. However I assume you only want to iterate the list of bounds and not change the collection, for this you only need an `IEnumerable` instead of a `List`. Since an `IEnumerable<Zone>` functions the same as an `IEnumerable<Bounds>` this is allowed. So if you indeed only want to read the elements of the `bounds` parameter, change the signature to this:

`public static bool BoundsOverlapsOtherBounds(Bounds bound, IEnumerable<Bounds> bounds)`

that should accept any `List` of `(Zone, Room, …)`

Hope this helps